# Python Scripting : AttributeError : 'SpaceTextEditor ' object has no attribute 'context'

Tags: python, scripting, image

I am trying to write a python script using the info panel.

The first part of the code is unwrapping a mesh which is executing successfully.

The second part is to change the viewport shading to MATERIAL which is used for rendering. But when I try to run the script I get this error .

[image: Attribute Error]

Thirdly, I am trying to import a .png image. But its not being displayed in the UV Editor.

The code is shown below:

```
import bpy
   for obj in bpy.data.objects:
     if(obj.type == 'MESH'):
       bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
       bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
       bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
       bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE') 
       bpy.ops.uv.unwrap(method='ANGLE_BASED', margin=0.001)
       bpy.context.space_data.context = 'MATERIAL'
       bpy.ops.material.new()
       bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//finger1.png", directory="C:\\Users\\KM\\Desktop\\blender\\Test 1\\", files=[{"name":"finger1.png", "name":"finger1.png"}], relative_path=True, show_multiview=False)
```

Anything regarding this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bpy.context.space_data` depends on the active window (clicking on the materials button the the property editor). This line can be removed.

Comment: @ideasman42 - So if i need to render it using the python script, I will have to keep the 3D view in Materials mode and then render it? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: To put it differently, the script would not give this exception if you ran it within the properties editor. However changing this button is not even important for the running of the script, so the line can be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a big advocate of avoiding bpy.ops as much as possible.  I wrote an example at http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/load-image-texture.html which might help you understand how to use python to create a material using an image texture:

Here is the most important bit:

```
def material_for_texture(fname):
    img = bpy.data.images.load(fname)

    tex = bpy.data.textures.new(fname, 'IMAGE')
    tex.image = img

    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(fname)
    mat.texture_slots.add()
    ts = mat.texture_slots[0]
    ts.texture = tex
    ts.texture_coords = 'ORCO'

    return mat

fname = "/var/tmp/blender/mohawk-seal0001.png"
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat = material_for_texture(fname)
if len(obj.data.materials)<1:
    obj.data.materials.append(mat)
else:
    obj.data.materials[0] = mat
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as your second point. Solved it like this:

```
threeD_viewport = None

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces: 
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                threeD_viewport = space

threeD_viewport.shading.type = 'MATERIAL'
```

Comment: Or a one-liner `next(s for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type=='VIEW_3D' for s in a.spaces if s.type=='VIEW_3D').shading.type = 'MATERIAL'`